# Error setting up my dotnet application docker

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, .net-core

I'm starting to develop in dotnet, and made a simple project following this link tutorial
http://www.macoratti.net/19/01/aspn_lnxsite1.htm

Then I went to do the part of launching a docker and followed the steps
http://www.macoratti.net/19/01/intro_docker7.htm

However when giving the command `docker container start MvcContainer` it appears the name of my container, but when accessing the route https://localhost:3000 does not load anything

my version of dotnet is 3.1.100

This is the configuration of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
LABEL version="1.0.1" description="Aplicacao ASP .NET Core MVC"
COPY dist /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","App1.dll"]
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? or how can I find out what's going wrong?

Comment: Does `http://localhost:80` show the app? The command in the question doesn't have the port number mapping from `80 -> 3000`, unless it has been abbreviated

Comment: I used the command "docker container create -p 3000:80 --name MvcContainer aspnetcoremvc/app1:1.0"

Comment: and yes I tested port 80

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but did you try the non-https version `http://localhost:3000`?

Comment: I tried the localhost http and https day route to ports 80, 8080, 3000, 5000 and 5001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build:

```
docker build -t aspnetcoremvc/app1:1.0 .
```

Run:

```
docker run -d -p <host port>:<container port> <image name>
docker run -d -p 3000:80 aspnetcoremvc/app1:1.0
```

For https endpoint you need to have certificates
https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/interlock/usage/tls/